# Move file to Teams SharePoint directory using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm trying to move a file to a Teams Channel\SharePoint directory using powershell. It appears to me that I only need three lines of code for proof of concept.  I'm using the -UseWebLogin to get my login information

$Output = Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\ToSharepoint\Test.txt

Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://My365.sharepoint.com/" –UseWebLogin

Add-pnpfile -path $Output -Folder https://My365.sharepoint.com/:f:/s/MyServicesInc/%20ITCommunications/Forms/AllItems.aspx

I've tried numerous strings for the destination but none of them seem to work. I'm currently receiving this error message,

Add-pnpfile : Access denied.
At line:1 char:1

- Add-pnpfile -path $Output -Folder  https://My365.sharepoint.com/:f:/ ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPFile], ServerUnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.AddFile
  ```

I am able to upload a file manually so I believe my credentials are not the issue but I don't know that for sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use the Url of your teams channel site url under following code:

> Connect-PnPOnline -Url
> "**[https://My365.sharepoint.com/sites/Team1-PrivateChannel38**"](https://My365.sharepoint.com/sites/Team1-PrivateChannel38**%22)
> –UseWebLogin

In addition, use a relative folder path like this:

> Shared Documents/Private Channel 38/Folder1

Here is my test which works well:

```
$Output = Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\lulu4.jpg
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Team1-PrivateChannel38" –UseWebLogin
Add-pnpfile -path $Output -Folder "Shared Documents/Private Channel 38/Folder1"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Julie, thanks so much for taking the time to comment!  The picture is also a great bonus!  I see exactly what you did and I can replicate it but still can't upload the file.  The one difference I noticed is that to the right of Team1 - Private Channel 38 I have the words  "Private Group."  Is there something special I need to do when that's the case? Thanks again!

Comment: If possible, please provide some screenshots and which parameters are different.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the interface I'm working with and what I'm using.  The only way I could get the picture in was to submit this as an answer, sorry about that. I'm still not able to get it to work.  I am a member of the group rather than the owner and I'm wondering if that is the issue although I can manually upload files and delete file from sharepoint.

$Output = Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\ToSharepoint\Test.txt

Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://My365.sharepoint.com/sites/UnitedWeStand" –UseWebLogin

Add-pnpfile -path $Output -Folder "Documents/IT Communications"

Thanks again!

[My Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ef01.png)